# Synthetic timestamp pandas

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-quicksight

I need to add a timestamp to a dataframe with the following settings:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/21/2020', 
periods=len(df))
```

I would like to know how to discard the miliseconds terms since I need to convert to this format  `Jan 1, 1400 00:00:00`  later in Quicksight.
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.floor('s')`:

dummy example:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2020', end='1/21/2020', periods=12)
date_rng.floor('s')
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-02 19:38:10',
               '2020-01-04 15:16:21', '2020-01-06 10:54:32',
               '2020-01-08 06:32:43', '2020-01-10 02:10:54',
               '2020-01-11 21:49:05', '2020-01-13 17:27:16',
               '2020-01-15 13:05:27', '2020-01-17 08:43:38',
               '2020-01-19 04:21:49', '2020-01-21 00:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```